# Bash script to check if mdadm is installed if not install it

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, raid, raid5

I am currently working on a bash script to create raid5 with 3 disks and one hotspare.

I am confused of how to create a script which first check if mdadm exist, if not it will install it and name it md5. (Raid voulme)

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup) I got this

> If your system has RAID support, you should have a file called
>   /proc/mdstat. Remember it, that file is your friend. If you do not
>   have that file, maybe your kernel does not have RAID support.

Issue this command and see the result:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

It should tell you that you have the right RAID personality (eg. RAID mode) registered, and that no RAID devices are currently active.

Comment: Yes! It tells me that I have raid1 active which I configured while installing the operative system (12.04).

Comment: @user3185936 Welcome and don't forget to mark it as answer

Comment: I checked in the /usr/bin folder and didn't find mdadm. That means that its not installed.

Comment: You could simply try at the terminal: mdadm and it should tell you if it is installed or not